# to validate file extension for uploading file in firefox

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, validation, file-upload

I created the upload page using with FileUpload server control. And I used regular expression validator to validate file extension.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="AttachmentUpload" CssClass="text" size="58" Width="376px" IE:Width="385px" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true"
                                                ID="AttachmentUploadRequire"
                                                runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="AttachmentUpload"
                                                Display="None"
                                                ErrorMessage="Please select a file to attach."/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                                                    runat="server"
                                                    ErrorMessage="The selected file type is not allowed!"
                                                    ControlToValidate="AttachmentUpload"
                                                    Display="None"
                                                    ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(\.[mM][pP]3|\.[mM][pP][eE][gG]|\.[sS][wW][fF]|\.[dD][oO][cC]|\.[tT][xX][tT]|\.[jJ][pP][gG]|\.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|\.[pP][nN][gG]|\.[xX][lL][sS]|\.[pP][dD][fF]|\.[gG][iI][fF]|\.[pP][pP][tT])$"/>
```

It is Ok for chrome and IE but not Ok for firefox. How can I solve it?

Comment: How is not ok for Firefox?  Are you seeing an error?  Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: The regular expression validator is working on other browser finely. But the validator is not working on firefox. I mean the error alert box is not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a Javascript function and **call it on your form button's OnClientClick event**. This approach works for all browsers:

```
function checkFileExtension() {
    var filePath = document.getElementById('AttachmentUpload').value;

    var validExtension = 'xml';
    var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (ext.toLowerCase() == validExtension)
        return true; //xml file is valid

    alert('The file extension ' + ext.toUpperCase() + ' is not allowed!');
    return false; //all other types of files are not valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox only supplies the file name information, not its path information. Your regular expression parses for path information, thus it fails.

I believe that other non-IE browsers also only send the file name. The purpose is to protect the user's privacy (i.e.: you could obtain their system username if the file was stored under My Documents in windows).